# How to perform the inverse of a fetch in GIT?

Tags: git, cloud, push, fetch

**The Setup**

I have a local network of 4 machines (**Dev1**, **Dev2**, **Server** and **Laptop**).

Server has what you might call the main repository.

The 2 Dev machines are where development happens.

```
dev..commit...dev..commit...dev..commit...dev..commit...dev..commit.
```

...and then eventually...

```
push to **Server**.
```

All good so far. This cycle works very nicely.

---

**The backup strategy**

**Laptop** has a clone of the same repository used by the other machines.
This clone has remotes to the repo from **Server**, **Dev1** and **Dev2**.

A scheduled task running on **Laptop** fetches all commits from all of the other repositories every day at ~3pm.

Because the backup operation is a fetch, **Laptop** manages to maintain a list of where everyone's repository is at without allowing their various heads to influence each other.

I consider this to be a good offsite backup, since the machine leaves with me each day.

---

**What do I want to achieve**

I would like to move this responsibility from my **Laptop** to another possibly cloud based server. **Cloud1**

However **Cloud1** will be unable to locate **Dev1**, **Dev2** or any other machine that sits behind our firewall.

So I thought it reasonable to see if I could find a way of scheduling a push (sorry for the ambiguous terminology) from each Dev machine to **Cloud1**.

However now we reach the crux of the matter.

**The Problem**

Push is not the opposite of fetch.

If each of my dev machines try to push to **Cloud1**, each of their master branches (at a minimum) will attempt to update the cloud machine's master pointer.

Push is good when you want to share the work you've been doing with others.

I need a command which is good for backing up all of your commits and heads on a remote machine without affecting that machine's own heads.

I'm not convinced this is currently possible. I am investigating other approaches. 
This question pertains purely to git's ability to push without a merge. (Not strictly accurate, but having read this far you understand what I mean - I hope)

Comment: have you considered branching?

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the refspec you want to update.
So, if **Dev1** does

```
git push cloud +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/dev1/master
```

and **Dev2** does

```
git push cloud +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/dev2/master
```

they won't clash.

Note that you can configure the push refspec differently for each developer if you don't want to specify it all on the command-line, but I assume this will be scripted anyway.

Comment: Would this result in an update of the dev1/master and dev2/master remotes on Cloud1? As if Cloud1 had issued a fetch against each?

Comment: Yes - you're just creating two seperate branches (one per developer), and controlling the relationship between each developer's `master` and their branch explicitly instead of relying on the default/implied refspec

Comment: NB. so long as you make sure the `refs/remotes/...` path is unique (doesn't clash with the existing remotes), you can test this immediately with the laptop.